# How to display twitter statuses (pseudo html) using wpf (powerboots)

Tags: wpf, powershell, twitter

I have a text like this: 'Rails on IIS7  http://is.gd/vWPn' (it's a tweet by shanselman). I'd like to display it somehow using wpf. How should I preprocess the text and what controls use then?

Current solution is that I create 2 controls: Label and Hyperlink and add them into a TextBlock.
In powerboots it looks like this:

```
boots { border -borderthickness 10 -cornerradius 10 -borderbrush orange `
  { textblock { `
     label 'Rails on IIS7' -backgr green; hyperlink 'http://is.gd/vWPn' -backg 'red' } `
} } -width 400
```

However it looks quite strange - the hyperlink is shifted, I have no idea why. [alt text http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/1363/powerbootshl.jpg](http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/1363/powerbootshl.jpg)

One more question - is it ok to use Label to display the text? I'm asking because it seems that label can not wrap it's content. Should I use TextBlock or something completely else?

Comment: Are you wanting to display this specific text? Or are you wanting to display any tweet generically?

Comment: I want to display any tweet generically. Older versions looked like this: http://twitpic.com/3nf36 (however, there is no link)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest, I know nothing about PowerBoots. However:

I think you're on the right track as far as preprocessing the text goes.  You're going to need to parse the text from the *tweet* and figure out what's an `@` reference, what's a `hyperlink`, etc.

With this knowledge, you can then begin to populate your TextBlock, as I think you've tried to do in the code you've presented.  However, you're right in thinking that a `Label` is not the right choice.  In fact, the Element that you want is called a `Run`.  A `Run` is little more than a run of text, hence the term.  Ultimately, for your simple example, the code would look like:

```
boots { border -borderthickness 10 -cornerradius 10 -borderbrush orange `
{ textblock { `
    run 'Rails on IIS7' -backgr green; hyperlink 'http://is.gd/vWPn' -backg 'red' } `
} } -width 400
```

assuming I got the syntax for PowerBoots right.

Comment: If you work with PowerShell, check PowerBoots if you need to use WPF from PowerShell. http://huddledmasses.org/powerboots-tutorial-walkthrough/

I haven't seen this "Run", because it's not listed in controls list. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.aspx However, it works now much better. Thx